# How to check empty-ness of a folder recursively, excluding a specific folder?

Tags: android, shell, directory, is-empty

I'm not an expert of linux/unix shell commands.

Sorry for being so specific, but I would like to ask:

Suppose I have a folder and I need to check that it's empty of "simple" files (all files excluding folders/directories), and also ignore a specific folder inside it. How do I do that?

Do note that I intend to run the command on Android (without using the API, because I intend to use it for checking out the info of protected folders), so it might have less commands than the normal shell of linux/unix .

If needed, I can run multiple shell commands, and check the output of each of them before going to the next command.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
find /path/to/dirs/* -type d -empty \( ! -iname "DIR TO IGNORE" \)
```

---

Please check out the below examples, this will list all empty folders within /home/test - excluding the `ruby` folder

```
[user@server:/home/test]# mkdir shell bash php ruby perl
[user@server:/home/test]# touch shell/testing.sh
[user@server:/home/test]# find /home/test/* -type d -empty \( ! -iname "ruby" \)
/home/test/bash
/home/test/perl
/home/test/php
```

Comment: is the "DIR TO IGNORE" an exact path or a relative path inside the "/path/to/dirs/" path? maybe you could put an example?

Comment: it would be relative as you said, would be a folder within /path/to/dirs/*    - I have added an example to my answer

Comment: i'm happy that you've given an example. the result is not as i've asked , but maybe i didn't ask well enough. i need to know if the specified folder is empty from files (both in it and in its subfolders, recuresively), and ignore a specific folder from the searching . just a true/false result.

Comment: I think that Android doesn't support the "empty" argument. Can I instead list all regular files in the directory, excluding a specific path?

Comment: Try this `find /home/test -type f -and -not -path /home/test/ruby/*`

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, and I've also tried to change the paths to include/exclude the "/*" , "/" and "*" parts

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've handled it by checking for each of the files recursively, and ignored those that are in the path i wanted to ignore using Java.

The terminal command is:

```
find /PATH/TO/FOLDER/* -type f
```

If anyone else can also make it skip a specific folder, that would be nice.